# Error: Int is not convertible to NSRange

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, nsrange

I'm getting the error:

> int is not convertible to NSRange

on `var range:NSrange = 0`:

```
   let predicate = NSPredicate(block: { (city: AnyObject!, b: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Bool in
            var range:NSRange = 0;  //convert error happens here on 0
            if city is NSString {
                range = city.rangeOfString(searchBarText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
            }

            return range.location != NSNotFound
        })
```

any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSRange` is a `struct` with members `location` and `length`, not an `Int`

use the initializer

```
var range: NSRange = NSRange(location:0, length:0)
```

or the convenience function

```
var range: NSRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your init statement was wrong. `NSRange` is a struct with a `location` and a `range` value. Change that to:

```
var range = NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0)
```

Comment: I realize that a factory method exists but removed the named arguments. I prefer the more verbose constructor which removes ambiguities on the params: var range = NSRange(location: 0, length: 1)

Comment: This is the correct answer, as you should use NSNotFound for a "nil" or invalid NSRange. You shouldn't use 0 for the position, as that's a valid index, which makes this a valid range. If you look at the value of NSNotFound you'll see it's NSIntegerMax, not 0.